# Steps to follow while parsing second file through yyparse

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I want to parse two files. I have Yacc/lex code which generates the parser.

It works fine when I parse the first file (a.txt) but when i parse the second file (b.txt) it returns error (syntax error), but when i parse second file(b.txt) first it can parse it smoothly.

My guess is that after reading first file when it start reading second file some buffers or states are not cleared. So i wanted to ask to know do I have to reset some buffers or states which parser maintains before proceeding for parsing second file.

I cannot paste my code over here as it is too large.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer to this through some other question. The problem was in clearing the buffer so if you add a

> `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER`

Befor opening a new file it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want a reentrant parser. Bison at least supports this, I'm not really sure if yacc does this, but switching to bison should be effectively painless.

Add `%pure-parser` in your grammar file.

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/bison/bison_66.html

Comment: One more problem with this is that i have to change the complete code which use global static variables. Also note that I am not parsing two files simultaneously. They are being parsed one by one so I do not necessarily require a reentrant parser.